# Mail Merge sendgrid c#

Tags: c#, sendgrid

Using the [SendGrid C# API](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp). I have spent several hours looking through the documentation [here](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/blob/master/ExampleNet45Project/Example.cs) and more frustratingly [here](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/blob/master/tests/SendGrid.Tests/Integration.cs#L79). I have searched through several SO posts and messed around with the code but to no avail.

Basically I have an email template that begins like so:

```
--------------------------
{RecipientName},

here is the rest of the email body...
--------------------------------
```

I simply want every instance of {RecipientName} to be the first name of the person receiving the email. I see there is a Personalization class but there doesn't seem to be any documentation or actual examples of how to use it for this purpose.

Here is the code which works great for actually sending the email to the recipients:

```
List<EmailAddress> allRecipients = new List<EmailAddress>();
for (int i = 0; i < notice.AllRecipients.Count; i++)
{
     _Logger.Info("processing recipient number " + i);
     Employee e = _companyLogic.GetEmployeeByEmployeeId(notice.AllRecipients[i].EmployeeId);
     EmailAddress email = new EmailAddress(e.EmailAddress, e.FirstName + " " + e.LastName);
     allRecipients.Add(email);
}

msg.AddTos(allRecipients);
```

It would seem the perfect place to add the Substitution would be in the for loop. But I am not seeing how this can be accomplished.

Comment: do you know the `{RecipientName}` before you enter the loop? You could do `notice.AllRecipients.OrderByDescending(r => r == "{RecipientName}")` This would make them the first that it adds. You could also add it separately before you get in the loop and then remove it from `notice.AllRecipients` when the person is added.

Comment: You can make Razor templates, even if you aren't using Asp.Net.  Works really well, can be a little wonky setting up.  https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the documentation you need: https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/blob/master/USE_CASES.md#transactional_templates